# url rewrite with htaccess, add parameter in start domain name

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've a problem in url rewriting. i want to rewrite my url that is currently displaying as
**`domain.com/index.php?lang=fr`**
and i want to show it like
**`fr.domain.com`**

any help will be appereciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this code on `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` on `domain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)lang=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}? [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: sorry it is redirecting me to fr(lang) directory but i don't want to redirect on this directory. it should work as currently working like i can get it $_GET['lang'] and pass it.

Comment: It is redirecting `domain.com/index.php?lang=fr` to `fr.domain.com/index.php` is that not what you want?

Comment: i don't want to redirect, i just want to rewrite url. means url should be displayed like fr.domain.com but in real it should be work as domain.com/index.php?lang=fr

Comment: Are the both domains on same host and pointing to same DOCUMENT_ROOT?